# set css property separately for each layer on hover (ggiraph)

Tags: css, ggiraph

Using `ggiraph`, I'd like to set `css` properties differently for each `ggplot` `geom_` or layer using hover. In the example below, how might I set the stroke for the second `geom_rect_interactive` to blue on hover but keep the first layer stroke red on hover (keeping the `data_id` the same so both respond to hovering over either layer)?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)
p <- 
  ggplot(
  data = data.frame(id = seq(3), x = 1:3, y = 1:3)
) +

  # red stroke
  geom_rect_interactive(
    mapping = aes(
      xmin = x, xmax = x - 0.1,
      ymin = y, ymax = y - 0.1,
      data_id = id
    )
  ) +

  # blue stroke
  geom_rect_interactive(
    mapping = aes(
      xmin = x, xmax = x + 0.1,
      ymin = y, ymax = y + 0.1,
      data_id = id
    )
  )

x <- girafe(ggobj = p)
x <- girafe_options(
  x,
  opts_hover(
    css = "stroke:#ff0000;"
  )
)
x
```

I'm guessing I might be able to do something like assign some custom `css` class to a particular layer (e.g., `.mystroke {stroke:#0000ff;}`) but not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am one of the authors) This is not currently possible, we have not considered this case (we will if we can implement it).

For the moment, it is only possible to specify a CSS per shape type. An example will be more meaningful, it is copied from:

https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/articles/offcran/customizing.html#detailled-control-1

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)


dataset <- mtcars
dataset$carname <- row.names(dataset)

gg_scatter <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = disp, y = qsec, label = carname, 
  data_id = carname, color= wt) ) + 
  geom_point_interactive(size=3) + 
  geom_text_interactive(vjust = 2) +
  theme_minimal()

girafe(ggobj = gg_scatter2, 
  options = list(
    opts_hover(
    css = girafe_css(
      css = "fill:purple;stroke:black;",
      text = "stroke:none;fill:red;"
    )
  )
  ) )
```

Comment: The package has been very helpful! I haven't dug into the details of how the functions are made, but what if we could name or add a class as a parameter to the interactive layer (or maybe this is already done, in which case we could query its name)? Just thinking out loud here.